# React input: force value through setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am creating a react component that allows users to allocate a bill to a number of assignees.

I am using a dynamic number of controlled number inputs, where the value is determined by the component state (proposedBillSplit). I do so by preparing an array of inputs like so:

```
render() {
    let assigneeRows = [];

    for (var i=0; i< this.state.proposedBillSplit.length; i++) {
            assigneeRows.push(
                <input type="number"
                    value={this.state.proposedBillSplit[i][2]}
                    onChange={this.billSplitChanged}/>
             );
     }
     return (<div>{assigneeRows}</div>)
}
```

This inputs alone work fine, however I also want to add a button that splits the bill equally and assigns the new equal amount to each input, by updating the state.
I tried doing so like this:

```
this.setState({
    'proposedBillSplit':
        [this.state.proposedBillSplit.map((allocation, index) => {
            return [
                this.state.proposedBillSplit[index][0],
                this.state.proposedBillSplit[index][1],
                newSplit]
        })]

});
```

However I get a react error as it appears forcing an input change by changing the state makes the input uncontrolled (see error below)? Is there an issue with my code, or does react actually only allow input value changes to occur through user inputs?

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type number to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Comment: Have you checked the state you are setting to, are any of those values `null` ?

Comment: yes, checked that. I prepared the new state array outside of setState and the new array looks fine... Is what I am trying to do even conceptually possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: it means `newSplit` is null / undefined so `value={this.state.proposedBillSplit[i][2]}` changes the input to an uncontrolled one.

Comment: Just figured it out... It's the syntax in my map function. I had brackets around the map function, but map already maps to an array. So I was effectively mapping within this.state.proposedBillSplit[0] instead of this.state.proposedBillSplit.
thanks both, you probably saved me a couple hours by narrowing down the issue!